# Does the Slow spell limit the number of Eldritch Blast beams?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, cantrips

This question comes from something stated in an answer to [another one of my questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158295):

> [Regarding *eldritch blast*] This spell allows you to make a single attack that targets multiple creatures, by making several attack rolls.

---

The [*slow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell states:

> [...] Regardless of the creature's abilities or magic items, it can't make more than one melee or ranged attack during its turn [...]

Note I am aware the *slow* spell also affects the casting of spells, so let's assume a caster always succeeds on the d20 roll.

And then there is the [*eldritch blast*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eldritch-blast) spell which states:

> A beam of crackling energy streaks toward a creature within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 1d10 force damage.
>
> The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels: two beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th level. You can direct the beams at the same target or at different ones. Make a separate attack roll for each beam.

Does the *slow* spell prevents you from creating more than one *eldritch blast* beam?

Comment: Related: [Does the slow effect affect all attack types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158279/48793)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, because *eldritch blast* consists of multiple attacks.

The rules on [making an attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) are as follows:

> Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or **making an attack roll as part of a spell**, an attack has a simple structure.
>
> 1. **Choose a target.** Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or a location.
> 2. **Determine modifiers.** The DM determines whether the target has cover and whether you have advantage or disadvantage against the target. In addition, spells, special abilities, and other effects can apply penalties or bonuses to your attack roll.
> 3. **Resolve the attack.** You make the attack roll. On a hit, you roll damage, unless the particular attack has rules that specify otherwise. Some attacks cause special effects in addition to or instead of damage.
>
> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: **if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.**

As you can see, if something involves an attack roll, it is an attack. You choose a target for the attack, determine relevant modifiers to the attack roll, and resolve the attack (by making the attack roll, seeing if it hits, and rolling damage and resolving any other effects).

The [*eldritch blast*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eldritch-blast) cantrip consists of at least one attack roll, of course - but at level 5 and up, it consists of multiple attack rolls:

> A beam of crackling energy streaks toward a creature within range. **Make a ranged spell attack against the target.** On a hit, the target takes 1d10 force damage.
>
> The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels: two beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th level. **You can direct the beams at the same target or at different ones. Make a separate attack roll for each beam.**

Obviously, at level 1-4, it is clearly an attack. Now the question is: at level 5 and up, is it considered one attack, or multiple attacks?

**By default, anything that consists of multiple attack rolls consists of multiple attacks.** This is clear by looking at the rules for making an attack quoted above; it is a sequence of targeting something, determining your modifiers, and making and resolving the attack roll.

---

Unless stated otherwise, anything that involves multiple attack rolls - including *eldritch blast* for higher-level characters - generally has you go through this process, step by step, for each attack. Rules designer Jeremy Crawford seems to support this claim in [his response to a related tweet in an unofficial tweet from June 2015](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/614588258404597760):

> *Eldritch Blast: are the attacks resolved in parallel or sequence? Do you have to pick all the targets first before rolling?*
>
> **Multiple attacks on the same turn aren't simultaneous, unless a feature or spell says otherwise.**

Clearly, each beam of *eldritch blast* goes through the steps of "making an attack" from the beginning, one after the other; you choose a target for each beam, determine modifiers (though this will almost certainly be the same for every beam unless something grants advantage/disadvantage on a single attack), and resolve each attack separately.

Crawford also unofficially addressed this claim in [his response to another tweet asking about exactly this back in September 2014](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/512337371979739136):

> *Was it intended for Eldritch Blast to be considered one attack with multiple attack rolls & thus to activate Hax only once?*
>
> **Hex triggers each time you hit the hexed target, so eldritch blast can trigger it on each hit.**

The [*hex*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex) spell (PHB, p. 251) says:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the target **whenever you hit it with an attack**.

As Crawford states, *hex* causes each attack of yours that hits to deal extra damage. At higher levels, *eldritch blast* consists of multiple beams, each with a separate attack roll. If, as Crawford states, *eldritch blast* triggers the extra damage of *hex* on each hit, then by necessity, each beam of *eldritch blast* must be a separate attack (as part of the same spell).

---

Finally, we can compare *eldritch blast* to a different feature that *is* considered "one attack" despite having multiple attack rolls, according to the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=4): the Hunter ranger's Whirlwind Attack feature.

> **Can a ranger move between the attack rolls of the Whirlwind Attack feature?**
>
> No. Whirlwind Attack is unusual, in that it’s a single attack with multiple attack rolls. In most other instances, an attack has one attack roll. The rule on moving between attacks (*PH*, 190) lets you move between weapon attacks, not between the attack rolls of an exceptional feature like Whirlwind Attack.

So if Whirlwind Attack consists of multiple attack rolls, why is it considered "a single attack" - and what makes it exceptional or different to other things with multiple attack rolls?

To answer that, we need to look at the description of the feature. The [Hunter ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter)'s Whirlwind Attack option for its [Multiattack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Multiattack-340) feature says:

> You can use your action to make **a melee attack** against any number of creatures within 5 feet of you, with a **separate attack roll for each target**.

Note that the other option for the Multiattack feature, Volley, seems to be worded similarly:

> You can use your action to make **a ranged attack** against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your weapon’s range. You must have ammunition for each target, as normal, and **you make a separate attack roll for each target**.

Whirlwind Attack, like *eldritch blast*, consists of a separate attack roll for each target. However, the key difference seems to be that the feature itself says you make "a melee attack" (singular) against multiple creatures, rather than "melee attacks" (plural).

The same holds true for Volley, except it says "a ranged attack" (still singular); though not mentioned in the SAC ruling, Crawford confirmed that it's also considered a single attack in [this unofficial tweet from September 2014](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/512336707828457473).

It's definitely a weird bit of phrasing to hinge upon, but it's the only thing exceptional about the feature. The distinction can't hinge on what's left unstated; [there are no secret rules](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136). Therefore, the thing marking Whirlwind Attack and Volley as "a single attack" must be the fact that they tell you to make "a [melee/ranged] attack", despite targeting multiple creatures.

Otherwise, every single spell that consisted of multiple attack rolls - such as *scorching ray*, or *chaos bolt* if the energy leaps, or any single-target attack as part of a spell that then has the sorcerer's Twinned Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option used on it - could also be considered "a single attack"... which would make Whirlwind Attack (and Volley) very *un*exceptional.

Comment: It is perhaps noteworthy that *scorching ray* has wording that differs from the other two spells you've mentioned. The others include the phrase "Make a new/separate attack roll" whereas *scorching ray* states "Make a ranged spell attack for each ray." Also perhaps worth addressing is the wording similarities between Whirlwind Attack and *eldritch blast*: "make a ranged attack [...] make a separate attack roll for each target." vs "Make a ranged spell attack [...] Make a separate attack roll for each beam."

Answer (score 10):

## No

Eldritch Blast is a single ranged spell attack that happens to be able to cast multiple beams at higher levels. The fact that there are multiple attack rolls does not change the fact that it is a single ranged spell attack. The spell Slow prevents the extra attack feature and limits the creature to use either an action or a bonus action but not both. The Slow spell only affects Eldritch blast because it has a casting time of 1 action.

The official [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA042) says that "Whirlwind Attack is unusual, in that it’s a single attack with multiple attack rolls." As stated it the related question. Eldritch Blast would be counted the same as this example.

Comment: I disagree with this, and have made my case in [my own answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159269/33569). If *eldritch blast* was considered "a single attack", there would be essentially nothing unusual about Whirlwind Attack/Volley; the only thing unique about Whirlwind Attack/Volley as opposed to spells consisting of multiple attack rolls is that Whirlwind Attack/Volley literally says you make "a [melee/ranged] attack" against multiple creatures.

Comment: The rules explicitly disagree with this answer: "Whenever you make an attack roll, you’re making an attack." Multiple attack rolls is multiple attacks, *always*.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That's not true, as the SAC explains for the Whirlwind/Volley feature.

Answer (score 1):

## **No.**

Ignoring the following portion of the spell for now:

> If the creature attempts to cast a spell with a casting time of 1 action, roll a d20. On an 11 or higher, the spell doesn't take effect until the creature's next turn, and the creature must use its action on that turn to complete the spell. If it can't, the spell is wasted.

You are casting a spell with a casting time of 1 action, this is allowed. That spell just happens to have multiple attack rolls.

> [...]Regardless of the **creature's abilities** or **magic items**, it can't make more than one melee or ranged attack during its turn.[...]

Eldritch Blast's ability to create more than one beam, thus giving multiple separate attack rolls, is a feature of the spell itself, not a feature of a **creature ability** or **magic item**.

***I want to fire multiple eldritch blasts while under the effect of Slow***

Use the **Ready Action.**

> Sometimes you want to get the jump on a foe or wait for a particular circumstance before you act. To do so, you can take the Ready action on your turn, which lets you act using your reaction before the start of your next turn.

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

> When the trigger occurs, you can either take your reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore the trigger. Remember that you can take only one reaction per round.

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs. To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of 1 action, and holding onto the spell's magic requires concentration. If your concentration is broken, the spell dissipates without taking effect.

**Slow** states:

> [...] Regardless of the creature's abilities or magic items, it can't make more than one melee or ranged attack **during its turn.** [...]

Since the reduction to the number of attacks you can make only applies during your turn, you can simply state you are readying your action to cast Eldritch Blast, releasing it anytime after your turn for multiple beams. This come at the cost of burning your concentration, but it does let you fire multiple beams, RAW, while under the effects of the Slow spell.

With such an easy workaround, I as a DM would just allow multiple beams to occur on your turn to avoid needless semantics.

Comment: Note, you are still subject to the effect of slow that requires you to roll a d20 prior to casting, to check and see if it goes off on your next turn instead.

Comment: And you should also note that *you still must define a perceivable trigger*, and [defining in terms of your turn doesn't work](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48137/62294).

Comment: That said, welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. This is a very interesting idea, taking advantage of the fact that the slow effect says "your turn", but there are some details that I think still need to be worked out (see previous comments).

Comment: Edited to ignore that portion of the spell for the purposes of this discussion.
The perceivable trigger could be as broad as "The next time any creature does anything." or you could simply just state "After half a second passes I release my spell."

Comment: The first could probably work, but the second doesn't. In-universe, all the turns are happening at the same time, you aren't standing around waiting for your turn.

Comment: That's true that a round is simultaneous, which begs the question as to why Slow would word it's effects to only limit you during your turn. I would still allow a player to use time as a *perceivable trigger,* perhaps letting the attack go off at another point in initiative. Still, the simple fact that you can, using nothing but a change of wording, get multiple attacks from EB while under slow, leads me to believe you should be able to get them at all times.

Comment: I've never had a player try this, but it's a loop hole I will be patching out from now on.