# Do multiple beams from Eldritch Blast happen simultaneously or not by RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, cantrips

After reading [Can you move between the separate attacks of a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169144/35259), I was quite surprised to learn that *[eldritch blast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eldritch-blast)* can be considered to not fire the beams simultaneously.

Given that the spell's duration is instantaneous, I assumed it was clean cut that they all fired simultaneously. However, [Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/07/09/parallel-attacks-or-sequence/) seems to think differently:

> *Jeremy Soard: @JeremyECrawford Eldritch Blast: are the attacks resolved in parallel or sequence? Do you have to pick all the targets first before rolling?*
>
> **JeremyECrawford: Multiple attacks on the same turn aren't simultaneous, unless a feature or spell says otherwise.**

However, there are many who don't accept Crawford's rulings as being meaningful. However, it is enough for me to realise that it's not as clean cut as I originally assumed.

I'm interested in knowing what the RAW interpretation is, discounting the above information from Crawford.

**So, based on RAW, meaning only what's printed in a published book, do multiple beams from *eldritch blast* happen simultaneously or not?**

Note that I haven't found any duplicate Q&As on this site, except possibly those that use the above quote from Crawford as an answer. I'm specifically asking about a RAW-only interpretation.

Comment: Possibly a repeat of [When are targets picked for spells with multiple “missiles”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51722/60913) ?

Comment: Somewhat related, this question asks about how many attacks *eldritch blast* is considered to be: "[Does the Slow spell limit the number of Eldritch Blast beams?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158577)"

Comment: Yeah the *magic missile* bit doesn't apply. I thought of it because https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51727/60913 seems to be a functional answer to your question as well.

Comment: I believe providing an example of when the distinction matters would help make the question a bit clearer (earlier comment removed). I *think* one example would be whether you can select your targets one-by-one or instead must select them all immediately when you cast the spell

Comment: @Medix2 Wasting beams on a dead creature is probably the most obvious example. Honestly, at this point, I feel like the answers to the question Odo linked above probably does answer mine. I'm probably going to close this as a dupe of that, unless anyone thinks they shouldn't be because the questions "aren't technically duplicates" or something, but I kinda think they are.

Comment: @Odo Thanks again for pointing me to that Q&A; all the answers to that do answer my question quite nicely.

Comment: "Crawford seems to think differently"--how do you figure? His answer, as always, is "No, unless it's yes, in which case yes."

Comment: @Mark There Crawford is rather clearly stating that *eldritch blast* has its attacks occur non-simultaneously. Or at least, it's rather clear EB does *not* "state otherwise" like *magic missile* does

Comment: @Medix2 I'd rather this not be marked as a dupe of [Do multiple hits of Repelling Blast happen simultaneously or in succession?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93419/35259) since the only answer there is this Crawford quote, which kinda defeats the point of my question. Besides, the dupe Odo found is a more direct duplicate; I think "Do multiple hits of Repelling Blast happen simultaneously or in succession?" should just be listed as a "related" in a comment at best.

Comment: @NathanS Alrighty, works for me, though I do think they're incredibly similar this is already closed as a duplicate so all's good. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @NathanS I've added that to the dupe list since that question has since received a thorough answer from our friend Medix2